# Cakephp different suffix for tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following requirement:

to create db tables with the names like:

topics_group1

topics_group2

topics_group3

topics_group4

Is there any way to create model "TopicsGroup" and associate that with different table names based on suffix in cakephp?

P.S. please do NOT suggest to create different table for groups and another table to map group & topics. Thanks

Comment: Based on what suffix? In general, yes, you could override the model constructor and/or hack deeper into the Cake core, but it sounds like a really non-standard bad idea.

Comment: @deceze, I realized that is non-standard idea. Not sure if good or bad at this moment however I would like to try that and so want to know cakephp can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the model you should have:

```
class TopicsGroup extends Model{
    public $useTable = 'topics_group1';
}
```

but I don't know how to dynamically change the suffix in a Cake way, you could just have 3 Models(TopicsGroup1 ...)

Comment: hmm, nice idea, will try to change $useTable dynamically